# Testing a method which deletes the test file

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a method which deletes a file after processing. I'm writing tests for it, using the same file in the test project. But as expected, this file will be deleted after each execution. How can I make it... come back each time?^^ Sorry if it is very stupid from me

Comment: Have you attempted to save the file to a physical location on your computer via the code?  If not, then it is only resident in memory and will be dropped when the method which created it closes.

Comment: Why don't you just create the file before you run the method from your test?

Comment: I was just adding this file in my project folder. The methods takes it's path, then calls remove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code you're testing deletes it then you'll obviously need to recreate it before each test. You can make use of the 'set-up' facility in your unit-testing library to do it.

If you're using Visual Studio Unit-Testing Framework, then this method is created by decorating it with a `TestInitialize` attribute:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Setup()
{
   // recreate file here
}
```

If you're using NUnit then use the `SetUp` attribute:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    // recreate file here
}
```

Comment: And if you're using xUnit, just do it in the fixture constructor.

Comment: For completeness you can delete the file (if it exists) in the test tear-down method to save leaving files lying around and potentially causing the set-up to fail if a test fails.

Answer (score 1):

I had a kind of similar situation where I needed to load in a sqlite db and perform actions on it, then dispose of it.

I ended up including the file as an embedded resource, streaming the resource out and creating a file in the test setup method and then removing it afterwards in the cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

In your test setup, you would create a test version of the file, then execute your method, then check that the file is gone.

It sounds like perhaps your test is using the 'production' version of the file - this is a bad idea and to make your method more testable, it should be passed the name of the file to process and delete, so your can use a test file for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on the nature of the file and the test. Typically you would want to have your unit test generate the data that it is going to operate on, to ensure a consistent data set each time the unit test is run.

If that is not possible or feasible, then what I would probably do is make a copy of the file in the unit test, maybe with the same name plus a .test extension, and pass that file to the method you are testing.

If the method you are testing gets the filename on it's own somehow, then you can do the opposite; make a copy of the file before the method is called, then after the method executes, rename the copied file back to the original filename.